# Swiper slider grid shows incorrect order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I was making slider using Swiper and React.js.
I want to show 2 items in per page.
But it shows the items with incorrect order.
Swiper version: `10.0.0`
React version: `18`

Here is my code.

```
<Swiper
  ref={swiperRef}
  spaceBetween={0}
  allowTouchMove={true}
  touchMove={true}
  slidesPerView={1}
  grid={{
    fill: 'row',
    rows: 2,
  }}
  pagination={{
    type: 'fraction'
  }}
  className="mySwiper"
  modules={[Grid, Pagination]}
  onInit={(swiper) => {
    setPagination(swiper?.pagination?.el?.outerText)
  }}
  onSlideChange={onChangeSlider}
>
  {results?.map((item, index) => (
    <SwiperSlide key={index}>
      <div className="bg-[#e2e2e2] py-4 my-2 text-[#010101]">{index + 1}</div>
    </SwiperSlide>
  ))}
</Swiper>
```

Expected result:

```
First page
1
2

Second page
3
4

third page
5
```

Current result

```
First page
1
4

Second page
2
5

Third page
3
```

If I remove `grid.fill`, result is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What results do you get, when you set  slidesPerView={2}?